# Recommendations for music processing library?

Tags: audio, plot

I'm in a Music Theory class and for my final, I've decided to code a program that would output simple statistics about a given song. I was wondering, does anybody have any good libraries for such a task? I don't really like C++ or C, but if I'm forced to use them, I will.

I've tried MIT's Music21 for Python (I was excited, as I liked its features), but I never got it to work... Are there any libraries that can just give me raw data (frequencies plotted in time) of any given MP3 file? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys, but I've decided that this is too complicated of a task to accomplish in a few weeks for a class which doesn't even require this kind of stuff.

I think that I am going to use Snack for Python to generate some classical music, as that seems to be a bit more interesting to the non-programmers (I doubt my teacher would give me any credit for writing a beat-extraction algorithm from scratch).

Thanks to everybody who helped! I'm not done with Python and music *just* yet ;)

Comment: Agreed that frequency analysis or beat extraction of songs wouldn't quite fit in any music theory class I've been in :-), though they could be good jumping-off points for research in computer music. If your theory class focuses on analysis of Western classical music, you might consider the realm of programming that takes scores as input (i.e. starting with discrete pitches, rhythms, etc. as your input rather than raw audio) and does analysis on that. music21 looks like a great way to start there.

Comment: Heh, a bit late, but I settled with writing my own. I wrote a basic music library (half notes, chords, etc.) and linked it with a crude synthesizer (also in Python), which writes directly into WAV files. It got me my A ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find frequencies plotted in time with code you will probably have to do some frequency-domain transformations to obtain that, such as FFT or wavelets. What you obtain as raw data in an audio file is a discrete signal of time-varying voltage. Python has a built-in library for wav files, and with numpy you can do the FFT analysis on the signal. 
One suggestion I have is PureData (http://puredata.info/) , a visual programming environment for musical purposes. That software will help you a lot, and save you a lot of trouble with the DSP part of music software development. With PureData, you can use frequencies plotted in time easily. If the idea is to develop something for a music theory class, it is a great solution.

Comment: Wow, this is actually what I was looking for! Is there an API for this? I see that this program has its own language...

Comment: No, it doesn’t have an API. But in this site: http://jeraman.wordpress.com/2009/03/22/how-to-use-pure-data-as-a-api/ you can find a suggestion on how to work with it in a 'API-like' environment for Python.

Answer (score 0):

libsndfile for C/C++ is good, but maybe a bit low-level. What are you planning on doing with it?
You can look at `javax.sound.sampled` for Java too.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what I was planning, but I was hoping to make a few algorithms to try to display simple information about the music file being processed. I was hoping to use only raw data to extract a beat, number of instruments, etc. I'm not a big fan of C/C++, but Java looks nice, as I have to present this on a Mac. Thanks!

Comment: For beat analysis, you'll need to go pretty low level, C or Java may be your only option. Analysing the number of instruments is a *very* difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your are familiar with graphical programming languages (pd, max, reaktor) i'd recommend [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/).  It has an fft library, reasonable gui/graphics libraries, but its real strength lies in the SmallTalk language its based in, which provides rich Functional and Object Oriented facilities.  I find this system a real joy to work with.  It comes with an interactive interpreter which helps where development is more ad hoc than structured.

Try it, you might like it.